# jQuery UI Autocomplete On contenteditable with Multiple Selections

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, contenteditable, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I got jQuery UI Autocomplete working on a `contenteditable="true"` `div` by adding `$.fn.val = $.fn.html;` to the top of the function. However, every other feature that was working on an `input` element has now broken using a `div`. The features such as setting a minimum number of characters and allowing multiple selections doesn't work anymore. I get error messages such as `Can't find variable extractLast` and `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'val.split')`. Is there a way to let jQuery pull `text()` or `html()` from my `div` instead of trying to look for an `input` or `textarea`'s `val()`?

```
$(function() {

    $.fn.val = $.fn.html;

    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }

    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }

    $("#div")
        .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            highlightClass: "bold-text",
            autoFocus: true,
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength for multiple selections
                var term = extractLast(this.value);
                if (term.length < 3) {
                    $(this).autocomplete("close");
                    return false;
                }
            },
            source: function(request, response) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
            },
            select: function(e, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(", ");
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript's `this.innerHTML` instead of `this.value`, but this will retrieve tags as well. Or use jQuery's `$(this).text()` to get the text value from an [Object HTMLDivElement].